# JUnit 5 testReporter Kotlin Android doesn't print anything in report

Tags: android, kotlin, junit5, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to implement testReporter in JUnit5, using Kotlin in Android project, but i'm not getting anything in the test report...

my code is like that:

```
class TestReporterTest {
   
    @Test
    fun `Report Single Value`(testReporter: TestReporter) {
        testReporter.publishEntry("Testing my value")
    }
    
    @Test
    fun `Report Several value`(testReporter: TestReporter) {
        val myMap = hashMapOf<String, String>()
        myMap["name"] = "John"
        myMap["surName"] = "Doe"
        testReporter.publishEntry(myMap)
    }

}
```

the dependencies i use are these:

```
    // Aggregator dependency on JUnit api, engine, and params
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.0")

    //Instrumented Tests
    // 4) Jupiter API & Test Runner, if you don't have it already
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0")

    // 5) The instrumentation test companion libraries
    androidTestImplementation("de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-core:1.3.0")
    androidTestRuntimeOnly("de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-runner:1.3.0")
```

but I always get this...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the IntelliJ settings...

just do it like this... since logging/reporting is an IntelliJ feature, it should run the rest not Gradle. now it works.

[image]

Comment: That way you’re no longer using Gradle to run your tests, which comes with different problems. Eg filters in your Gradle test configuration are no longer honoured.

Comment: that is the only solution that one guy suggested when I created in JUnit5 github, but after all he admited that there is an issue with Gradle that should be considered...

Answer (score 0):

If you‘re running your tests with Gradle, then this issue may be the reason for your frustration: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4605

More lobbying to resolve this (allegedly simple) issue might help, but it also might not.

Comment: it seems no solution for this issue yet...

Comment: I found out it is a Kotlin Issue, on a Java project `TestReporter` worked fine...

Comment: Don’t think that’s the case. With a Java project configured the same way - in Gradle and IntelliJ - you’ll see the same behaviour.